# Subset R data.frame by index and name in one line

Tags: r, dataframe

Sample data.frame:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = c(7, 8, 9)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output:

```
df
#   a b c
# 1 1 4 7
# 2 2 5 8
# 3 3 6 9
```

I'd like to get the first and third columns, but I want to subset by name and also by column index.

```
df[, "a"]
# [1] 1 2 3

df[, 3]
# [1] 7 8 9

df[, c("a", 3)]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c("a", 3)) : undefined columns selected

df[, c(match("a", names(df)), 3)]
#   a c
# 1 1 7
# 2 2 8
# 3 3 9
```

Are there functions or packages that allow for clean/simple syntax, as in the third example, while also achieving the result of the fourth example?

Comment: I don't think so; `match` is what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `dplyr`?

For interactive use - i.e., if you know ahead of time the name of the column you want to select

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(a, 3)
```

If you do not know the name of the column in advance, and want to pass it as a variable,

```
x <- names(df)[1]
x
[1] "a"

df %>% select_(x, 3)
```

Either way the output is

```
#  a c
#1 1 7
#2 2 8
#3 3 9
```

Comment: Looks good; I'll play around and learn more with `dplyr`. What do you mean by "interactive" vs "dynamic" use?

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can combine `subset` with `select`.

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), 
b = c(4, 5, 6), c = c(7, 8, 9)), 
.Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")


df <- subset(df, select = c(a, 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can index `names(df)` without using dplyr:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = c(7, 8, 9)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
df[,c("a",names(df)[3]) ]
```

Output:

```
  a c
1 1 7
2 2 8
3 3 9
```